# How to change value via vb.net Webbbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, getelementbyid

Starting with this navigation call:

```
Webbrowser.Navigate("localhost")
```

the `Webbrowser.Document` object holds a ref. to a HTML object with the following attributes:

```
id="first"
name="first"
type="text"
value="something"
```

My question is; How do I change the value?

I have seen some posts about how to get the element via `getElementById`:

```
Webbrowser.Document.getElementById("first")
```

But i still have no idea how to change its `value`.

Comment: Posting from a mobile is no excuse for bad formatting or poor language. Please improve the question by correcting the formatting and trying to improve the language. Right now it's not possible to understand what it is you want. Add the output generated by `Webbrowser.navigate("localhost")` for example.

Comment: Omg you are doing so wrong.. Did you read my answer?

Comment: I could not possibly have read your answer when I wrote this comment, you had not written it yet. I could see what you where after from your own answer and have edited both post and answer for clarity so that this question might provide value to other users as well, it's not all about you you know ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it:

```
Webbrowser.Document.getElementById("user").setAttribute("value", "username")
```

Or if the element has no `id`:

```
Webbrowser.Document.getElementByTagName("input").getElementByName("user").item(0).setAttribute("value", "username")
```